# Change terminal command line format

Tags: unix, terminal, format, command, xterm

I was trying to change the format of my terminal from

```
john@example.com /home/directory
$
```

to this:

```
/home/directory>
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

I am using unix, xterm.

Comment: `export PS1="$PWD> "` should make it.

Comment: do u want to post that as an answer, so people can see...thanks

Comment: Sure! I just did. Glad it worked to you : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the following:

```
export PS1="$PWD> " #this will always show the dir you were when performing the command
export PS1='$PWD> ' #this is the correct
```

Note that this will work for your current session. To make it persistent, add the line to your `~/.bashrc` file.

For comprehensive information about this topic, you can check [How to: Change / Setup bash custom prompt (PS1)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html).

Comment: hey man..there seems to be a problem...it doesn't show the current working directory in the command line

Comment: like it keeps showing /home/directory even when I am in a different directory

Comment: Oh, I see. See my updated answer, it is just a matter of changing `"` for `'` so that it executes `$PWD` every time.